# how to remove last 'index.php' in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to remove last `index.php` in `laravel`?

I use Apache .htaccess but searched remove script but that is all remove index.php...

I want remove this

ex http:\domain.com/index.php/auth/index.php -> http:\domain.com/index.php/auth/index
ex http:\domain.com/index.php/auth/good.php -> http:\domain.com/index.php/auth/good

I want to remove last `index.php` use the `.htaccess` How can I remove last `index.php`?

Answer (score 1):

What people usually do is hide the `index.php` within the URL. This can be done by adding the following code to your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

That code will work for PHP Versions higher than 5.2.6 and mod_rewrite must be enabled in PHP in order for this to work.

If the PHP version that you are using is less than 5.2.6 then you can try using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This will remove inded.php from the URL.

Comment: do not work this.... i want 
http:\\domain.com/index.php/auth/index.php -> http:\\domain.com/index.php/auth/index 
and 
http:\\domain.com/auth/index.php -> http:\\domain.com/auth/index